# canCreateInstance in Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) service

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation

As far as I understand if I click `canCreateInstance`, then for each request that comes to the service, there is created a new thread and that request is executed immediately.

If `canCreateInstance` is disabled, then the requests will be put in a queue and they will be processed one at a time.

Is this correct? I am implementing a queue with `canCreateInstance` disabled. Do you know anything against something like this? How Can I start the service with `canCreateInstance` disabled

Comment: Are you just asking for the difference between a singleton and per-request workflows? See [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wfprerelease/thread/53e84ece-1618-4821-bc86-c9fbee25e03e)

Answer (score 5):

Given a WorkflowServiceHost receives a message matching the contract and operation name for the initial receive activity

If **CanCreateInstance** is true then WorkflowServiceHost will create a new instance of the workflow and deliver the message to the receive activity.

If **CanCreateInstance** is false then the WorkflowServiceHost will throw an exception

*There is no context attached to the incoming message for the service and the current operation is not marked with "CanCreateInstance = true". In order to communicate with this service check whether the incoming binding supports the context protocol and has a valid context initialized.*

The first receive activity in the workflow should always have **CanCreateInstance** = true otherwise the workflow cannot activate.

The reason this property exists is so we can have one Receive activity that works for both activating receives and continuing receives.

Comment: How do i add a WorkflowServiceHost to the WF service?